# What is 'word left' and 'word right' keycode in Karabiner-Elements?

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner

On Mac OS system,
I modified the config file of complex map, but can't find keycode of wordleft and wordright:

```
{
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "o",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "wordleft" # keycode is wrong
            }
          ]
        }
```

any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just remap 'option+right_arrow' to 'command+o' to solve my problem.

```yaml
{
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "o",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "right_arrow",
                "modifiers": [
                  "option"
                ]
              }
          ]
        }
}
```